# When a unique column is on the table, you only need to apply a filter on that column to make the transition happen

Tags: powerbi

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/learn/modules/dax-power-bi-modify-filter/5-context-transition

> When a unique column is on the table, you only need to apply a filter
> on that column to make the transition happen. In this case, Power BI
> applies a filter on the CustomerKey column for the value in row
> context.

I am looking for an example to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following tables with and without a unique `ID` column.

`Table1`

| ID | ABC | XYZ | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | x | 5 |
| 2 | a | x | 2 |
| 3 | a | y | 2 |
| 4 | b | y | 2 |
| 5 | b | z | 3 |

`Table2`

| ABC | XYZ | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | 5 |
| a | x | 2 |
| a | y | 2 |
| b | y | 2 |
| b | z | 3 |

Let's define measures

```
SumValue1 = SUM ( Table1[Value] )
SumValue2 = SUM ( Table2[Value] )
```

If you calculate each respective measure within the row context (e.g. using a measure in a calculated column) of the first row on each table, then the context transition will turn the row context into a filter context that looks like this for the first table

```
CALCULATE (
    [SumValue1],
    FILTER ( Table1, Table1[ID] = 1 )
)
```

but like this for the second table

```
CALCULATE (
    [SumValue2],
    FILTER (
        Table2,
        Table2[ABC] = "a"
            && Table2[XYZ] = "x"
            && Table2[Value] = 5
    )
)
```

Because there is no unique column in the second case, it's necessary to look at all of the columns to know which row we're referring to.

When there is a unique `ID` column, you can shortcut this since there is a one-to-one correspondence between rows and `ID` values, so that specifying the `ID` is equivalent to specifying the row and vice versa.